# Multiple body lines ... pear (php) mail

Tags: php

I'm using pear mail, its sending okay but I'm not getting all the $bodycopy lines even if the if statement variable are empty I should still see the top and bottom dashes in which I'm not. Is my format/coding for multiple body content off?

// SETUP EMAIL

```
    $Bodycopy = "This information was submitted via the solocup.com website and sent to you because of the location 
identified by the user. If this has reached you in error, please forward this email to ----";
    $Bodycopy. "<br>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br><br>";

if ($uxRequestType != "")      $Bodycopy. "What kind of information do you need? : " .$uxRequestType. "<br>";   
    if ($uxConsumerBusiness != "") $Bodycopy. "What type of customer or vendor are you? : " .$uxConsumerBusiness. "<br>";
    if ($uxGlobalLocation != "")   $Bodycopy. "Global Location : " .$uxGlobalLocation. "<br>";
    if ($uxCompany != "")          $Bodycopy. "Company : " .$uxCompany. "<br>";
    if ($uxFirstName != "")        $Bodycopy. "First Name : " .$uxFirstName. "<br>";
    if ($uxLastName != "")         $Bodycopy. "Last Name : " .$uxLastName. "<br>";
    if ($uxTitle != "")            $Bodycopy. "Title : " .$uxTitle. "<br>";
    if ($uxEmail != "")            $Bodycopy. "Email : " .$uxEmail. "<br>";
    if ($uxAddress != "")          $Bodycopy. "Address : " .$uxAddress. "<br>";
    if ($uxCity != "")             $Bodycopy. "City : " .$uxCity. "<br>";   
    if ($uxState != "")            $Bodycopy. "State : " .$uxState. "<br>";
    if ($uxZip != "")              $Bodycopy. "Zip/Postal Code : " .$uxZip. "<br>";
    if ($uxPhone != "")            $Bodycopy. "Phone : " .$uxPhone. "<br>";
    if ($uxFax != "")              $Bodycopy. "Fax : " .$uxFax. "<br>";
    if ($uxProductDesc != "")      $Bodycopy. "UPC or product description : " .$uxProductDesc. "<br>";

    $Bodycopy. "<br>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br><br>";

    if ($uxComment != "")          $Bodycopy. "Comments : <br>" .$uxComment. "<br>";

$Bodycopy. "<br><br>";
```

// PROCESS EMAIL

// mail server info...

```
    $from = $SendTo;
    $to = "Do Not Reply <----@---->";
    $bcc = "--@---";
    //$to = "Do Not Reply <---@-->";
    $subject = "--- Contact : " . $uxGlobalLocation;
    $body = $Bodycopy;
    $host = "-----";
    $port = "25";
    $username = "donotreply@---";
    $password = "----";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Bcc' => $bcc,
    'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'port' => $port,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
    header ('Location: /index.php?option');
    exit();
    //echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
```

Comment: what's the point of a negative vote down if you're not going to explain what's wrong. its a valid question and i've provided source code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step :

Try replacing

```
 $Bodycopy.
```

by

```
 $Bodycopy.=
```

on all your lines.

Comment: @ceejayoz huh, whats invalid can you please give a solution or more advice.

Comment: @adrien oh i thought he was referring to your answer as being an invalid syntax. thanks